# How to create a text area which takes styles

Tags: css, html

I am writing an application, the use case is admin can enter some text in text area, the same will be displayed to the logged in user.
Here my problem is, if admin copies some code from some editor like eclipse/ intelliJ IDE, the code and style also should get copied to the text box.
So that user would be able to see it in proper format/style.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Kishna

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible.
The textarea is not designed for that purpose.

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) for further information.